# Host header differs from Target in handshake request for WebSocket

Tags: python, azure, websocket, reverse-engineering, burp

I am intercepting WebSocket traffic from the garage door opener app called Linear ([iOS](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/linear-smart-garage-door/id1216916239)/[Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.linearproaccess.smartcontrol&hl=en_US&gl=US)) and it looks to use Azure guessing by the domain names (`trafficmanager.net`, `cloudapp.net`, etc...).

When it makes it's initial HTTP request to upgrade to WebSocket, it sends this request to `https://linr-cs-tm-prod.trafficmanager.net:8080` though the Host header is `11323322-00AC-55F0-C09E-A903E123A25C`:

[image: picture of burp repeater showing HTTP request to upgrade to websocket]

When I try to replicate this in Python:

```
SERVICE_URL = "ws://linr-cs-tm-prod.trafficmanager.net:8080/Message.svc"
class Linear:
    """Class used for a Linear account."""

    message_id = 0

    async def login(self: Linear, email: str, password: str):
        """Login to a linear account."""
        async with websockets.connect(
            SERVICE_URL,
            origin="LinAccess-Android/1.3.16",
            open_timeout=30,
        ) as websocket:
            print("connected!")

    async def get_sites():
        """Get sites available under this account."""
```

It just results in a TimeoutError.

What do I set as Host?
Why is Host set this way?
Is the random ID as a Host an artifact of Burp?
Or is this a requirement for Azure?

I've tried extracting the CA certificate and using that as SSL context, removing the Host header, setting SSL to false, and changing `ws` to `wss`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by switching from the `websockets` library to `aiohttp`'s websocket library.